# Git Hub cloning speed so slow

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, https, github

i am trying to clone some trees from GitHub but getting much slower speed. I was getting around 25mbps speed two days ago but now i am getting 1mbps max on cloning. I tried several different repos and also tried with ssh and https but still getting slow speed. I then i tried --depth 1 along with git clone but it also didn't help. I don't whats is the issue i speed tested my computer and it is getting full speed. I am on kubuntu 23.04 lunar lobster.